# Здравствуйте, программа выдаёт такую ошибку

Tags: python

как исправить ошибку

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/ADMIN/PycharmProjects/untitled11/6 лб и 5 лекция.py", line 133, in      tom = Person ("Human", "black",) TypeError: **init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'weight1' and 'food'

вот сам код

```
class Mammals:
    kind = "белка"
    height = "20 см"
    hair = "рыжая и короткая шерсть"
    eyes = "чёрные круглые глаза"
    weight = "280 г"
    def __init__(self, kind, hair ):

        self.__food = "рослини і м'со"
    def set_food (self, food):
            self.__food = food

    def get_food (self):
        return self.__food+""

    def display_info (self):
        print ("Привіт, я ", self.kind,". ", self.hair, self.eyes, self.weight, self.height, 
    self.get_food())

    class Person (Mammals):
    kind1= "человек"
    height1 = "в среднем 150-170 см "
    weight1 = " в среднем 50-80 кг"
    def __init__(self, kind1, height1, weight1, food ):
        super().__init__(self, food)
        self.kind1 = kind1
        self.height1 = height1
        self.weight1 = weight1

    def display_info(self):
        super().display_info()
        print ("Привeт, я ", self.kind1,". ", "вес мой", self.weight1, ". ", "рост мой", self.height1, ". 
    ", "кушаю обычно", self.get_food() )


   tom = Person ("Human", "black",)
   tom.display_info ()
```

Comment: Для чего вы создаете атрибуты класса, а потом переопределяете их в конструкторе?

Comment: Вы посылаете 2 аргумента в персону, но она принимает 4 и спрашивает где еще 2 ?